# Python bs4 write html tag to file without encode

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('input.html', encoding="utf-8"), 'lxml') #local html file
soup.select_one("#target").clear()
soup.select_one("#target").insert(0, "<h1>Heading</h1>")

with open("output.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
  file.write(str(soup))
```

This what i get, it not output by tag but str

```
<div id="target">&lt;h1&gt;Heading&lt;/h1&gt;</div>
```

But i want

```
<div id="target"><h1>Heading</h1></div>
```

How can i do that? thanks.

Comment: I think you want to create an element and insert it. You are just inserting text (with less than and greater than symbols that happen to be in the text). See this answer (and the link to the documentation, which has an example where a div is created with text inside it): [how-to-add-elements-to-beautiful-soup-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186752/how-to-add-elements-to-beautiful-soup-element)

Answer (score -1):

`&lt, &gt` and other similiar charachters are representations of the < > brackets. To convert them, you need to unescape them. To do so:

```
import html
newstring = html.unescape(stringname) #You must store it as a variable since strings are immutable
```

Comment: This is a method for escaping HTML, but the OP wants to include the tags in the output without escaping them.

Comment: Oh shoot, my bad I confused myself, let me edit my post.

Comment: It should be unescape, not escape

Comment: It's still not the best way to do the task - depending on when you call `html.unescape`, you might unescape things outside the `<h1>Heading</h1>` tag. If there is any user input in extra HTML being unescaped, it could lead to [XSS vulnerabilities](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/). Better to make an element object and add it to the BeautifulSoup object than trying to unescape strings.

Comment: Fair, I wasn't really considering vulnerabilities.